# Java Mail SendFailedException 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

Ran into this error on our production server (of course things still work on the test server), but email stopped sending.

```
Email error: Invalid Addresses
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

I added some debugging to some common code:

`MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
InternetAddress[] toAddrs = InternetAddress.parse(email);
System.out.println("Setting TO Recipient to " + email);
for( InternetAddress ia : toAddrs ){
  System.out.println("  InternetAddress: " + ia.toString());
}
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddrs);
...
...
Transport.send(message);
} catch (SendFailedException sfe) {
  Address[] invalidAddrs = sfe.getInvalidAddresses();
  System.out.println("[EmailHelper] SendFailedException: " + sfe.getMessage() + "  -- " + InternetAddress.toString(sfe.getInvalidAddresses()));
  System.out.println("-- end SendFailedInspection\n");
}`

And the output I'm seeing is baffling (email address changed):

`Setting TO Recipient to clay@clay.com
  InternetAddress: clay@clay.com
[EmailHelper] SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses  -- apple
-- end SendFailedInspection`

I mean, literally it says "apple"!

I build the JAR on MacOX and deploy to Amazon Linux. Is that where "apple" is coming from? I send SMTP messages to AWS Simple Email Service (which works fine on our other services).

This code has been working for months, but it seemed to change overnight (possibly related to a `yum update`).

Anyway, very odd thing if you have any ideas. Thanks!

**Edit** JavaMail debugging info (personal stuff redacted):

`04/12/2018 14:12:59 : 571449 Send Note with Reports to clay@clay.com Failed
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
Setting TO Recipient to clay@clay.com
  InternetAddress: clay@clay.com
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-host-aws.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-2762711029 LtFXRutjiksFKUW
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-host-aws.com", port: 465
EHLO ip-172-31-58-4.ec2.internal
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<clay@clay.com>
250 Ok
RCPT TO:<clay@clay.com>
250 Ok
RCPT TO:<apple>
501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided
DEBUG SMTP: Valid Unsent Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   clay@clay.com
DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   apple
DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
RSET
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    ...
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1715)
    ... 7 more
QUIT
221 Bye`

Where does that "RCPT TO:" come from? What is this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting any other recipients on the message?  Add `message.writeTo(System.out);` just before Transport.send to see what recipients are actually set on the message.

Comment: @BillShannon That was it! Another place in the code was setting a BCC recipient. Who had a bad email address, "apple" . . . so messed up. But that was the problem, so thank you.